# properties window is messed up

Tags: interface, customization

Whenever I click a tab lets say material I have to press the MMB and drag my mouse to the right or left instead of scrolling normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you accidentally set the properties window to horizontal aliment. If your properties window looks something like this, that is indeed the problem.
[image: properties window]

All you have to do to fix it is <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> in any of the blank area and choose *"Vertical."*

[image: animated gif - change properties window aliment]